# NodeJS: Can't read binary data from tcpdump using child_process.spawn

Tags: node.js, child-process, tcpdump

I can't read binary data from `tcpdump -w -` in NodeJS.

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
spawn('tcpdump', ['-w -']).stdout.on('data', (data) => console.log(data.toString()))
```

It works with text data (without `-w -`).

I've tried with -U and verified that the libpcap I have on my machine export `pcap_dump_flush`. I can see with `strace` that `tcpdump` is indeed outputting the data. If I spawn another `tcpdump` with -r - and attach the stdout of the first one to it the data is passed to the second `tcpdump`. But the stdout data listener is never called and calling `stdout.read` returns null.

Note:
I'm aware of pcap, pcap2 and pcap-master but they don't seem to be maintained anymore and didn't compile with the latest version of node and I'd rather use tcpdump anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me if you separate the arguments like so.

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
spawn('tcpdump', ['-w', '-']).stdout.on('data', (data) => console.log(data.toString()))
```